# winforms devexpress GridView value loses focus on unbound column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

I have a cell inside of a devexpress `GridView`. The cell Contains a `ComboBoxRepositoryItem` inside of it, when it loses focus the Value is reset. On `selectedIndexChange`, the `combobox` changes the lookAndFeel of the App. I changed the  `e.Column.UnboundType` to `String` or `Object` and added the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event. The event never fires. Here is what the code looks like.

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "Value" && e.IsSetData)
            {
                _userEnteredData = e.Value.ToString();
            }
            else if (e.Column.FieldName == "Value" && e.IsGetData)
            {
                e.Value = _userEnteredData;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you enter a FieldName for the unbound column. Typically, this will be the same value as the column name for unbound columns.

Comment: it has a fieldName of "Value"

Comment: Where is the "_userEnteredData" value coming from?

Comment: It is a private variable in the class being set on SelectedIndexChange for the combobox. But the problem is even though I am binding the event I can't get it to fire. Let me post more code maybe that will help.

Comment: Actually the value is null I am not setting it until that event fires. It is just being a private variable in the class.

Comment: There are several tickets on the DevExpress support center that explain why the CustomColumnUnboundColumnData event may not be fired:

https://www.google.com/search?q=CustomUnboundColumnData+event+never+fires&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Top reasons include:

1. The column is not visible
2. The FieldName for the column is not unique or it conflicts with a field name in the grid's data source